# noclassdeffounderror in a simple networking program. I am using Eclipse IDE to run java programs

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

class IpAddr {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello Jagadeesh...>!!");
        try {
            InetAddress ia=InetAddress.getByName("www.facebook.com");
            System.out.println(ia);
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException uhe) {
            System.out.println("ip address of facebook is not found. :(");
        }
    }
}
```

In console: while running
    E:\myworkspace\network_practice\src\stage1>javac IpAddr.java
    E:\myworkspace\network_practice\src\stage1>java IpAddr

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IpAddr` (wrong name: s
    tage1/IpAddr)

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

`E:\myworkspace\network_practice\src\stage1>cd..`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not declare a package in your class so it goes to default package.But you have stage1 folder.

Comment: Yes, and the console should be something like this : E:\myworkspace\network_practice\bin>java stage1/IpAddr

Answer (score 0):

> NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not
>   able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during
>   compile time.

Source: http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Therefore I would check if you have added everything neccessary to your class path.

Comment: As I am using Eclipse IDE, i think the class path is set correct and besides this is the only program showing this error. All my other programs are running fine.
As i am using only 2 more classes InetAddress & UnknownHostException additionally & they are also imported as you can see, i think it may be the other reason.
Anyways I am just a beginner, and please help me and let me know if there is anything i have to know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jagadeesh,
it might be the case that your InetAddress jar version might not be supported